# Installing Minecraft mod on Mac OS X

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, macos

I was trying to get the Minecraft mod "Minecraft Is To Easy" (MITE) for Mac and can't get it to work.  I tried following these steps, http://mecodegoodsomeday.wordpress.com/2014/03/30/installing-mite-minecraft-is-too-easy-mod-on-macos/

- I would download MITE, unzip the file.
- paste the 1.6.4-MITE folder into the minecraft "versions" folder.
- copy the version 1.6.4.jar into the 1.6.4-MITE folder, rename it to "1.6.4-MITE.jar".
- unarchive the 1.6.4-MITE.jar then paste the contents of the "class" folder  (that was was inside the 1.6.4-MITE folder) into the unarchived 1.6.4-MITE.jar and keep duplicates.
- delete the META-INF folder.
- turn the unarchived 1.6.4-MITE.jar back into a .jar using the terminal.

Then I would run Minecraft and click "Edit Profile" and change the version to 1.6.4-MITE and click play.  Minecraft would run but nothing would be changed except that it was now running version 1.6.4, when it should of been running 1.6.4-MITE.

Comment: On OSX, for some reason - Minecraft dislikes it when you delete the META-INF folder. (As in becomes unusable even unmodded if the META-INF folder is deleted)

Comment: Minecraft would open it would just act like it was playing 1.6.4 instead of 1.6.4-MITE.  Does that still sound like the META_INF folder?

Comment: Is there any way you can obtain a log? They can be found in `%AppData%\Roaming\.minecraft\logs`. Look for the one that is for your launch... Alternatively, launch again and then after it closes, pick from the latest log file. (Note that you'll need to extract the .gz to get the .log file. You can use 7-Zip to do that.)

Comment: @aytimothy Just a follow-up as this question is for OS X: the path is `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` and 7-Zip is unnecessary as OS X can handle .gz extraction natively.

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks for the heads up - I forgot that it was OS X. But yeah: As correct; OSX messes up when you delete the META-INF folder, whereas Windows doesn't really do anything.

Comment: But even if you don't delete it it still messes up.

Answer (score -3):

Ok for your question all you have to do is follow my guide.

open Terminal and type

cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft
Step 2 = Copy 1.6.4.jar to this folder =

cd 1.6.4-MITE
cp ../1.6.4/1.6.4.jar original.zip
Step 3 = Rename it to 1.6.4-MITE.jar =

skip this step

Step 4 = Open 1.6.4-MITE.jar using WinZip or 7Zip =

First, in terminal type “open .” to fire up the Finder in this folder
In Finder, double-click on “original.zip” – it will create a folder called “original”

Step 5 = Open meta inf and delate the files with mojang in the name folder inside =

In Finder, open your “original” folder, and open the META_INF folder in there
then delete any files which have Mojang in them.

Step 6 = Copy contents of class Files folder into 1.6.4-MITE.jar =

This is the key place where Windows and the Mac differ. If you drag the contents of “class Files” to the “original” folder, it will clobber important files. Instead, open the “class Files” folder in Finder, select all of its contents (first click on a.class, then press Cmd-a to select all), then drag those files to the “original” folder. It will ask if you want to keep or replace. IMPORTANT: hold down the Option key, and the “Skip” button turns into “Keep Both”. Select that.

This procedure does the important interleaving, then create the new, modified jar file with these commands (you have to have the “JDK” installed):

cd ../original
jar cf ../1.6.4-MITE.jar .
Step 7 = Move MITE Resource Pack 1.6.4.zip to the resourcepacks folder in .minecraft =

this is right, except drag it to “~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks”

Step 8 = Run the Minecraft launcher and edit your profile to use 1.6.4-MITE version =

Step 9 = Play Minecraft and select the MITE Resource Pack =

Comment: You've just copy and pasted the instructions from the link in OP's question…